# Are virtue ethicists committed to the naturalist fallacy (especially if naturalists)?

Tags: ethics

### I start out noting some vague and knotted definitions of "non-natural" that suggest virtue ethics is natural, to ask whether a natural virtue ethics can be robust *without committing the naturalist fallacy*.

> Moore accused anyone who infers that X is good from any proposition
> about X’s natural properties of having committed the naturalistic
> fallacy. Assuming that being pleasant is a natural property, for
> example, someone who infers that drinking beer is good from the
> premise that drinking beer is pleasant is supposed to

Surely vices and virtues are not "supernatural"; at the least, they don't seem to depend on God or occult explanation

---

> Somewhat surprisingly, Moore in effect also argues that most forms of
> non-naturalism are also guilty of what he calls the naturalistic
> fallacy. In particular, he argues that so-called “metaphysical
> ethics,” according to which goodness is a non-natural property
> existing in “supersensible reality” also are guilty of the
> naturalistic fallacy.

I think, *somewhat vaguely*, this is where Hume's phrase (you can't) "derive an ought from an is" overlaps with Moore ("[There](https://philosophynow.org/issues/83/Hume_on_Is_and_Ought) would have to be no analytic bridge principles linking the moral and the non-moral. The moral words would have to be indefinable or at least not definable in terms of natural properties or concepts. This was a thesis made famous by the Cambridge philosopher G.E. Moore (1874-1958) who thought it a fallacy, the ‘Naturalistic Fallacy’, to define the word ‘good’ in terms of anything else."). Virtues and vices definitely exist, and so it must be more or a less a fact - an "is" - that someone has behaved bravely, from which we seem able to "infer" they are good, at least pending ethical nihilism.

---

> It is also sometimes suggested that non-naturalism is the thesis that
> moral properties are sui generis and irreducible (see, e.g. Pigden
> 1993: 421–422), and indeed this is one of the most distinctive aspects
> of Moore’s account of goodness

But it would be wrong to say that vices and virtues are "irreducible" and don't reduce to behaviour or at least behaviour coupled with cognitions of the situation etc..

---

> Most often, ‘non-naturalism’ denotes the metaphysical thesis that
> moral properties exist and are not identical with or reducible to any
> natural property or properties in some interesting sense of ‘natural’.
> However, just which sense of ‘natural’ is most apt in this context is
> highly controversial and I shall return to this point shortly.
> Understood in this way, non-naturalism is a form of moral realism and
> is opposed to non-cognitivist position

I think we can be non-cognitivists about virtues and vices: "hurrah to your honesty".

---

etc.

---

**If the naturalism I embrace prohibits strong realism about moral and intellectual value**

> some accounts of moral realism see it as involving additional
> commitments, say to the independence of the moral facts from human
> thought and practice, or to those facts being objective in some
> specified way

(and I do think - CF e.g. [analytic moral naturalism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/naturalism-moral/#WhyMoraNatu) - which strikes me as somewhat absurd and far too new age - that this form of realism is impossible for a "naturalist" in the very general sense: that quark was "cute"... no, it just has a "2 megaelectron-volts mass") **then am I committing the naturalist fallacy by claiming:**

1. it is a fact that someone has behaved honestly
2. it is a fact that someone is honest
3. whatever anyone thinks, honesty is preferable
4. whatever anyone thinks, honest persons are preferable
5. we are obliged to be honest persons
6. we are absolutely obliged to be honest persons
7. we know we are absolutely obliged to be honest persons.

(these are just claims that seem essential to me to an increasingly more robust 'virtue ethics')

> Moore accused anyone who infers that X is good from any proposition
> about X's natural properties of having committed the naturalistic
> fallacy

If so, how can we make sense of virtue and vice without committing the naturalist fallacy (whether or not it's ok to do so)?

Comment: for some reason i thought I was asking a different question to what I ended up asking (I thought - in my haste - I had provided reasons for them being non-natural as well as natural). So this long question may not hang together in a helpful way

Comment: I don't think you understand in what sense virtues are irreducible. What is irreducible is not the physical actions, but the judgment of the action. Your list of claims you introduce "preferable" and "obliged" without reducing those to naturalist terms. What exactly do you mean when you say we are "obliged". Moore is claiming that this question has no answer other than the answer that obligation is an independent notion that cannot be reduces to material properties.

Comment: Have you read Moore? Does he mention virtue? Why are you asking me to define "obligation"? "What is irreducible is not the physical actions, but the judgment of the action.": for Moore? What do you mean by saying a "judgment" can be "irreducible", that someone judges you as brave without reference to anything you do? Crazy @DavidGudeman

Comment: "Your list of claims you introduce "preferable" and "obliged" without reducing those to naturalist terms": the point of listing them was to ask if they were irreducible! etc. @DavidGudeman I am not saying "physical actions" can or cannot be reduced. I have no idea what you're complaining about and what you think I'ver misunderstood

Comment: you're right i need to edit the question anyway @DavidGudeman the sprawl was too much ha

Comment: right I think I nearly got what you mean @DavidGudeman are you suggesting that the second section wrongly interprets what "analytic bridge principles" mean: they aren't "good people act bravely" but......?

Comment: From the quotes, I would think that "analytic bridge principles" means some way to define things like virtue and obligation using natural language what has no moral language in it (like "virtue" and "obligation").

Comment: so Moore is saying we can't say "good people are honest and don't tell lies" @DavidGudeman ? in which case does that answer my question at all?

Comment: i probably should have read some articles before posting the question :/ @DavidGudeman

Comment: No. There is no fallacy in deriving "beer is good" from  "beer is pleasant" with a major premise "pleasure is good". Virtue ethicists explicitly endorse some values or purposes (like "flourishing", *eudaimonia*, etc.) that serve as major premises. McDowell even calls them "second nature" after Aristotle and it is normative by design. Why those attach to creatures like us is a further question that can be pondered naturalistically, e.g. evolution tends to instill such drives into such creatures, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-virtue/#ObjeVirtEthi).

Comment: do you mean "no, not for virtue ethics" or "no, and not just for virtue ethics" @Conifold just trying to make sense of what you seem to be providing a concise argument for, one that is new to me. i mean "pleasure is good" is a premise of utilitarianism and surely utilitarians might rile Moore (rightly or wrongly)

Comment: Another premise of utilitarianism, and consequentialism generally, is that only consequences matter. And it is not shared either by deontology or by virtue ethics, e.g. *eudaimonia* requires virtuous acting regardless of the consequences. But since Hume almost all of them posit some normative tenets to bridge the is-ought divide.

Comment: "The only proof capable of being given that an object is visible is that people actually see it…. In like manner, I apprehend, the sole evidence it is possible to produce that anything is desirable is that people do actually desire it...
G. E. Moore (1873–1958) criticized this as fallacious. He argued that it rested on an obvious ambiguity: Mill has made as naïve and artless a use of the naturalistic fallacy as anybody".

Comment: Mill's "naturalistic fallacy" is similar to your "major premise", if "artlessly" argued for by Mill @Conifold anyway, I'm not sure what you're getting at  besides thinking about why you yourself might disagree with Moore (not especially relevant?)

Comment: FWIW I *probably* agree with your "no" anyway, but due to the claims 1-7 not necessarily  or obviously relying on anything about "reducibility" or "analytic bridge principles" (which i *think* may just amount to "good" being the fundamental term of ethics), realist or otherwise, not the irrelevance of those two

Comment: Just to be clear: your claims 1-7 are not doing what Moore says is the naturalistic fallacy. You are not trying to define "obligation" using purely amoral terms. What would be a violation is saying something like "obligation is just what our culture says we have to do".

Comment: I think that's fair, though i still haven't seen enough to know what moore says on 'obligation' @DavidGudeman I think that 1-7 are also compatible with a naturalistically motivated moral non-objectivism, but *only just* (if there were a moral **fact** independent of what anyone thinks, then that would be objective); phew